# Reading Command line output Python

Tags: python, output

I have a problem where I am issuing a command using python and then taking in the values to create a list of services.

```
serviceList = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout =subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print serviceList
```

`command` is a working command that works perfectly when I copy and paste it into cmd, giving me a list of services and their status.

If I run this command it just returns nothing. When I print out serviceList it is blank.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: And what happens when you enter this in python?

Comment: oh sorry i completely forgot to put that in. it just gives me a blank space, or an empty list

Comment: Try `print serviceList.communicate()`

Comment: gives me the error str object has no attribute communicate, I will try this with os instead of subprocess
Edit: still gives the same error

Comment: I think you need to post more context for your code.

Comment: Using `ipython`, cannot reproduce. Working for me. `subprocess.Popen("echo 'hi!'", shell=True, stdout =subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()` returns `'hi!\n"`

Comment: My uneducated guesses for what's going on: 1. You're using Windows. 2. `command` outputs to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method instead of `stdout.read()` to get the value of `serviceList`.

Even the Python docs recommend it.

> **Warning:** Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the  other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Try this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout =subprocess.PIPE)
serviceList  = proc.communicate()[0]
print serviceList
```

`communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`. Here, i assign the first element of the tuple to `serviceList`.

Comment: This was the method that worked for me. I tried this beforehand but forgot a crucial thing. In my command string i should have put an 'r' in the beginning  "r'C:\Python27\A..." is how my command should have started instead of "'C:\Python27\A"

Answer (score 1):

If the program simply prints out a bunch of information then exits, an easier way (also no way for it to deadlock due to full buffer) to read output would be to call:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command)  # only call shell=True if you *really need it
stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate()  # blocks until process terminates
```

[docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

> *Calling shell=True with external input opens your code to shell injection attacks, and should be used with caution

Answer (score 0):

To save the standard output, add `output = serviceList.stdout.readlines()` to your code.

Comment: gives me the error that str object has no attribute stdout

Comment: When you run the command `serviceList = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()` are you sure that you are adding quotation marks around the command that you're trying to run? It's working fine for me in my python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the subprocess function check_output() which blocks and returns the output of the process as a byte-string. If you want to avoid blocking, you could make a function that calls this and use it as that target for a new Thread() e.g.

```
import subprocess
import threading

def f():
    print subprocess.check_output([command])

threading.Thread(target=f).start()
```